# Can I make web services in Laravel framework if the project is in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, android, laravel, web-services, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a project which is created in CakePHP 3 and I need to make an API for my Android app.

I have a little knowledge of Laravel and I can make API in Laravel. My question is can I make APIs in Laravel if my project is created in CakePHP 3?

Comment: this got an upvote? *huh?!*

Comment: we deal with code you wrote, not code that you want us to look for.

Comment: I am not looking for code, I just want a suggestion from experienced developers. that is it possible or not.

Comment: suggestions means opinionated and hold too many possible answers. The answer I see you accepted, is just that and is a comment if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create an api in Laravel and have it communicatie with another api or app which has been built in cake or any other framework.

An api simply has endpoints which can be called by any language/framework.

Comment: so do I make another folder for apis and setup laravel in that folder?

Comment: No. Definitely not.
    
The Laravel application should be separate from the cake application. 
That's how an API works, it's standalone.